# How can I obtain an asymptotic integral expansion at infinity?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I want to find the asymptotic expansion at $x \to \infty$ of the following function:
$$ I(x) \equiv \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-xt^3 \cos(t)} dt.$$
To do this, I defined

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Exp[-x t^3 Cos[t]], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

and then tried a series expansion around infinity with

```
Series[f[x], {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, and the output is nothing but the command I gave.
Why is this? And what can I do to make it work?

---

For what is worth, I evaluated the asymptotic expansion at hand and the result is (if I computed it right):
$$I(x) \sim \frac{\Gamma(4/3)}{x^{1/3}} + \left( \frac{1}{6} + \frac{8}{\pi^3} \right) \frac{1}{x} + \frac{7}{24} \frac{\Gamma(8/3)}{x^{5/3}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} \right), \quad x \to \infty $$

Comment: Is this really the code you used?  The first equation contains a syntax error.

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry about that.  No the code I used does not contain that error (I couldn't post from that computer so I rewrote the code)

Comment: It seems the new `AsymptoticIntegrate[]` function doesn't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, for a mathematical explanation on how to compute the first terms of the series with pen&paper check out [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672693/173147).

That said, here is what I ended up doing with Mathematica 10.0 to obtain an arbitrary number of terms of the asymptotic expansion.
I warn you that I'm not very proficient with Mathematica so any advice on how to optimize the code is welcome.

#### Find where the asymptotic contributions come from:

Rewrite the function as
$$I(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \!dt \,\, e^{-x g(t)}, \quad \text{where }g(t) \equiv t^3 \cos(t).$$
To find out what points in the interval of integration contribute at the asymptotic limit $x \to \infty$ we see what $g$ looks like in said interval:

```
g[t_] = t^3 Cos[t]
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, Mesh -> All]
```

which gives:

[image]

This tells us that the relevant terms will come from the integral at $t \to 0^+$ and $t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-$.

### Terms from $t \to 0^+$:

Get the Taylor expansion of $g$ around $t=0$ with

```
g0[t_] = Series[g[t], {t, 0, 8}]
(* Out[3] = t^3 - t^5/2 + t^7/24 + O[t]^9 *)
```

hence the leading term is
$$ g(t) \approx t^3, \quad t \to 0^+.$$
We thus want to make in the integral the substitution
$$ g(t) \equiv t^3 \cos(t) = s^3. $$
To use the variable $s$ in the integral we need to locally invert this relation to obtain $t_0(s)$.
We do this around $t=0$ with:

```
t0[s_] = InverseSeries[ (g0[s])^(1/3) ]
(* Out[4] = s + s^3/6 + (7 s^5)/72 + O[s]^7 *)
```

This allows us to finally compute the integral, which now looks like
$$ I_0(x) \sim \int_0^\infty \! ds \,\, t_0'(s) e^{-xt^3}, \quad x \to \infty $$
and in Mathematica:

```
Normal[t0'][s] Exp[-x s^3]
(* Out[5] = e^(-s^3 x) (1 + s^2/2 +(35 s^4)/72 ) *)
i0[x_] = Integrate[%, {s, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(* Out[6] = 1/(6 x) + Gamma[4/3]/x^(1/3) + (35 Gamma[5/3])/(216 x^(5/3)) *)
```

i.e.
$$ I_0(x) \sim \frac{1}{6 x}+\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{x^{1/3}}+\frac{35 \Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{216 x^{5/3}} + ... $$

### Terms from $t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-$:

Get the Taylor expansion of $g$ around $t=\pi/2$:

```
g1[t_] = Series[g[t], {t, Pi/2, 4}]
(* Out[7] = -1/8 \[Pi]^3 (t-\[Pi]/2)-3/4 \[Pi]^2 (t-\[Pi]/2)^2+1/48 (-72 \[Pi]+\[Pi]^3) (t-\[Pi]/2)^3+(-1+\[Pi]^2/8) (t-\[Pi]/2)^4+O[t-\[Pi]/2]^5 *)
```

The leading term is linear in $(t-\pi/2)$, hence we try the substitution
$$ g_1(t) \equiv t^3 \cos(t) = s.$$
We now invert this relation (locally around $t=\pi/2$ per series) to compute $t_1(s)$:

```
t1[s_] = InverseSeries[ g1[s] ]
(* Out[8] = \pi/2 - (8 s)/\pi^3 - (384 s^2)/\pi^7 - (256 (360+\pi^2) s^3)/(3 \[Pi]^11) - (16384 (182+\pi^2) s^4)/\pi^15 + O[s]^5 *)
```

With this substitution the integral will look like
$$ I_1(x) \sim - \int_0^\infty \! ds \,\, t_1'(s) e^{-xs}, $$
where the minus sign comes from a swapping of the integration limits needed in the substitution. In Mathematica:

```
Normal[t1'[s]] Exp[-x s]
(* Out[9] = e^(-s x) (-(8/\pi^3) - (768 s)/\pi^7 - (256 (360+\pi^2) s^2)/\pi^11 - (65536 (182+\pi^2) s^3)/\pi^15) *)
i1[x_] = - Collect[Integrate[%, {s, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0], x]
(* Out[10] = +((8 (8945664+49152 \[Pi]^2))/(\[Pi]^15 x^4))+(8 (23040 \[Pi]^4+64 \[Pi]^6))/(\[Pi]^15 x^3)+768/(\[Pi]^7 x^2)+8/(\[Pi]^3 x) *)
```

i.e.
$$ I_1(x) \sim \frac{8 \left(8945664+49152 \pi ^2\right)}{\pi ^{15} x^4}+\frac{8 \left(23040 \pi ^4+64 \pi ^6\right)}{\pi ^{15} x^3}+\frac{768}{\pi ^7 x^2}+\frac{8}{\pi ^3 x} $$

### Putting it all together:

Finally, the asymptotic expansion we wanted is obtained by simply summing $I_0$ and $I_1$:

```
if[x_] = Collect[ i0[x] + i1[x], x]
```

The result is, ignoring terms with power of $x$ lower than $x^{-5/3}$ (to include those I would have had to get more terms of the expansion of $I_0$):

$$ I(x) \sim \frac{768}{\pi ^7 x^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{8}{\pi ^3}}{x}+\frac{\text{Gamma}\left[\frac{4}{3}\right]}{x^{1/3}}+\frac{35 \text{Gamma}\left[\frac{5}{3}\right]}{216 x^{5/3}} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{x^{7/3}} \right) $$

### Conclusion

It seems I *almost* got it right! I must have missed some term in the computation of the denominator of the $x^{-2}$ term when I did it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup of explanation and code.

Answer (score 16):

Chances are it will behave similarly to `Integrate[Exp[-x t^3 ], {t, 0, π/2}]`. I show a numerical verification below. We'll use the dominant series term, which we can compute, for the above integral, and compare to numerical integrations of the one we cannot compute analytically.

```
ee1[x_] := Exp[-x*t^3]
ee2[x_] := Exp[-x*t^3*Cos[t]];
```

Let's get the candidate analytic term.

```
i1 = Integrate[ee1[n], {t, 0, π/2}]
s1 = Expand[Normal[Series[i1, {n, Infinity, 2}]]]

(* Out[158]= (3 Gamma[4/3] - Gamma[1/3, (n π^3)/8])/(3 n^(1/3))

Out[159]= (64 E^(-((n π^3)/8)))/(9 n^2 π^5) - (
 4 E^(-((n π^3)/8)))/(3 n π^2) + (1/n)^(1/3) Gamma[4/3] *)
```

The dominant term is `(1/n)^(1/3) Gamma[4/3]`. Let's test that against the integral of actual interest.

```
t1 = Gamma[4/3.]*Table[(1/n)^(1/3), {n, 10., 1000., 10}];
t2 = Table[NIntegrate[ee2[n], {t, 0, π/2}], {n, 10, 1000, 10}];
t1/t2

(* Out[178]= {0.889613957994, 0.93398701513, 0.950173592407, \
0.959053918538, 0.964797571829, 0.968871281155, 0.971937888145, \
0.974344883597, 0.976293611756, 0.977909513436, 0.979275174531, \
0.980447382775, 0.98146658481, 0.982362438315, 0.983157228034, \
0.983868051412, 0.984508264217, 0.985088464385, 0.98561717834, \
0.986101350477, 0.986546698826, 0.986957978112, 0.987339177279, \
0.9876936699, 0.988024330159, 0.988333623268, 0.98862367681, \
0.988896337531, 0.989153216798, 0.989395727565, 0.989625114446, \
0.989842478448, 0.990048797416, 0.990244943055, 0.990431695169, \
0.990609753656, 0.990779748639, 0.990942249097, 0.991097770216, \
0.991246779697, 0.991389703197, 0.991526929023, 0.991658812204, \
0.991785678043, 0.991907825207, 0.992025528451, 0.992139041267, \
0.992248596638, 0.9923544116, 0.992456686183, 0.99704297563, \
0.997081574489, 0.997118917853, 0.997155073418, 0.997190103398, \
0.997224065159, 0.997257011748, 0.997288992353, 0.997320052698, \
0.997350235384, 0.997379580188, 0.997408124317, 0.997435902639, \
0.997462947887, 0.997489290828, 0.997514960431, 0.997539984002, \
0.997564387337, 0.997588194736, 0.997611429257, 0.997634112709, \
0.99765626576, 0.997677908018, 0.997699058098, 0.997719733686, \
0.997739951586, 0.997759727841, 0.997779077673, 0.99779801561, \
0.997816555502, 0.997834710569, 0.99785249343, 0.997869916144, \
0.997886990235, 0.997903726729, 0.997920136175, 0.997936228675, \
0.997952013907, 0.997967501146, 0.997982699287, 0.997997616863, \
0.998012262067, 0.998026642763, 0.998040766509, 0.998054640568, \
0.998068271924, 0.998081667296, 0.998094833147, 0.998107775704, \
0.998120500959} *)
```

Getting pretty close to 1.

A rigorous proof would take more work though. I guess a possible approach would be to show that as `x` gets large, the dominant part of the integral is on a segment that shrinks toward the origin.

Comment: In order to obtain the `((2/Pi)^3)/x` term in the analytical expression provided in the Question, the upper limit of integration also must be considered.

Comment: That probably can be done by adding a term that can be integrated symbolically, and accounts for the behavior near `Pi/2`. Which is what you said, I'm simply advocating the same approach I did in the response, of using an explicitly integrated approximation.

Comment: This is very interesting. But is there no way to make mathematica handle the original integral itself? The procedure to obtain these kinds of expansions is pretty straightforward. I guess one has to resort to guide mathematica through the steps that one would do by hand?

Comment: What is the "procedure to obtain these kinds of expansions"?

Comment: I'm guessing that'd be integration by parts.

Comment: @J M. In the general case no, integration by parts doesn't work. For the leading term there is the Laplace method (check the wiki article). To obtain recursively all the terms one can use a generalization of it which is quite laborious to compute manually but also algorithmic enough to be (I think) easily done by a computer. I don't know what is called (or if it has a name) but I'll post myself an answer later showing a way I found to implement it with *Mathematica* (given my limited knowledge of it).

Comment: @glance, ah, of course. I believe the procedure you speak of is also described somewhere in Bender/Orszag…

Comment: @DanielLichtblau what I'm mainly curious about is: what kind of series expansions is Mathematica able to handle? Is there documentation on the techniques it tries to use to do it, so that one can guess what functions is it able to expand with some certainty?

Comment: @glance, it can do asymptotic and Laurent expansions, but as you might have already surmised, it can only do it for functions it "knows"; functions like yours that do not have an explicit closed form will require some legwork.

Answer (score 7):

Appreciating the nice answers of Daniel Lichtblau and glance I would like to note that they go in the classical mathematical direction.

Let me add here a different, Mathematica-oriented view on the problem at hand.
Let us make a table with the structure `{n, Integral}`  where I substitute `x=10^n` as follows:

```
    lst = Table[{n, 
   NIntegrate[Exp[-10^n t^3 Cos[t]], {t, 0, Pi/2}, MinRecursion -> 9, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 10]}, {n, 6, 15, 1}]

(* {{6, 0.00892996}, {7, 0.00414486}, {8, 0.00192387}, {9, 
  0.00089298}, {10, 0.000414484}, {11, 0.000192387}, {12, 
  0.000089298}, {13, 0.0000414484}, {14, 0.0000192387}, {15, 
  3.13507*10^-11}}  *)
```

Now this list may be fitted by any reasonable function one likes:

```
    model2 = a*Exp[-b*n];
ff = FindFit[lst, model2, {a, b}, n]
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> All],
  Plot[model2 /. ff, {n, 6, 15}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
  }]
```

yielding the fitting results:

```
(*  {a -> 0.893158, b -> 0.767558}    *)
```

as well as the plot to visually inspect the quality of fitting:

[image]

Here points show the list, while the solid red line indicates the approximation.

Substituting now

```
0.89*Exp[-0.77*Log[x]]
```

one gets a concise result:

```
0.89/x^0.77
```

yielding a good approximation to the integral. If you need this, of course.

Have fun!

Comment: It's not bad,. I had considered something similar. My one issue is that, in order to get the correct asymptotic expansion, one must know already what is the form of function to which the data will be fit.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau I did not know in advance, but just tried, and was lucky to fast find a reasonable form.

Comment: This seems good for small $x$, but it is hard to imagine it being good for very large $x$. Since you get $O(x^{-.77})$ and the correct asymptotics appears to be $O(x^{-.33})$ you must be off by something like a factor $10^{15}$ when $x \sim 10^{30}$. (this may not be visible though since $10^{-10}$ and $10^{-25}$ look quite similar when plotted.)